# Partial match for regular expression in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

How can I understand if a regex partially matches its subject?

I tried this:

```
Pattern.compile("^\\d").matcher("01L").hitEnd()
```

and this:

```
Pattern.compile("^\\d").matcher("01L").matches()
```

and they are both false, I want to test if the string starts with a digit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`matcher.find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) method:

```
boolean valid = Pattern.compile("^\\d").matcher("01L").find(); //true
```

PS: If you're using `find` in a loop or multiple times it is better to do:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\d"); // outside loop
boolean valid = p.matcher("01L").find(); // repeat calls
```

You are getting:

- `matches` attempts to match the entire input against the pattern hence it returns `false`.
- `hitEnd` returns `true` if the end of input was hit by the search engine in the last match operation performed by this matcher and since it didn't you get `false`